# Stop eclipse from creating .tracecompass directory

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-tracecompass

Upon opening my project in Eclipse 4.7.3.a on my ArchLinux a folder named `.tracecompass` keeps re-creating in the root folder of my project. If I remove it, it keeps recreating upon the next project opening.

How to disable the creation of this folder? Why is it created in the first place, when i don't want to use tracing futures?

I guess this is related to [Eclipse Trace Compass](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.tracecompass). My googling skills brought me [Trace Compass RCP User Guide](http://archive.eclipse.org/tracecompass/doc/stable/org.eclipse.tracecompass.rcp.doc.user/User-Guide.html), but I can't find there the info about how to disable it.

I guess I can `rm /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.tracecompass.*` plguins from eclipse, but that wouldn't be nice. Is there a better solution to this problem?

[image: Gui screenshot]

@edit:
The project is hosted on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc), here's the link to [.project](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamillibc/blob/master/.project) file.

Comment: Could you please show the content of the `.project` file in the project folder (which is visible in the _Navigator_ view)?

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Does removing the line `<nature>org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.project.nature</nature>` deactivate Trace Compass in this project?

Comment: I opened the project, removed .tracecompas folder ;) , closed the project and then opened the project and .tracecompass wasn't there! Feel free to post this as an answer so I can accept it. You have put me on the right track. Actually just found that this is exactly [this issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533420). After I renamed the project (again...), the tmf nature get's added to .project and .tracecompass folder get's created. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround to disable Trace Compass in a project:

1. Delete the `.tracecompas` subfolder
2. Close the project
3. Open the project

This should permanently remove the following line in the `.project` file (which is hidden in views like *Project Explorer*, but visible in the *Navigator* view):

```
<nature>org.eclipse.linuxtools.tmf.project.nature</nature>
```

See also [comment #2 in Eclipse bug 533420](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533420#c2).